# annuity interest payments

Tags: finance

Someone takes a loan of $S_1$ as an annuity at an annual interest rate $i$, paid back in *monthly* installments of $M$. Now I wonder how I can get the *annual* interest payments for each year $t$.

I can calculate the remaining debt after each year using

$$ S_{t}=\frac{M}{\frac{i}{12}} - \bigg(1+\frac{i}{12}\bigg)^{12}\times \bigg(\frac{M}{\frac{i}{12}}-S_{t-1}\bigg) $$

(e.g., wikipedia, adapted to have monthly payments). Using this, I can then calculate the interest numerically as $I_t = 12 \times M - (S_t - S_{t-1})$ but this approach fails in the last period when $M$ is paid only for a few months until $S_1$ is fully repaid. Therefore, I wonder whether anyone is aware of an equation to get annual interest payments analytically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loan $S=Ma_{\overline{n}|r}$ where $r=i/12$ in $n$ total months. 
If $S$ and $M$ are known we can easily find tne number of months to repay the loan 
$$
S=Ma_{\overline{n}|r}=M\frac{1-(1+r)^{-n}}{r}\quad\Longrightarrow\; n=\frac{\log\left(\frac{M}{M-rS}\right)}{\log(1+r)}
$$
and the number of years is $m=n/12$.

At any time $k$ (month) the interest payment is
$$
I_k=rMa_{\overline{n-k+1}|r}=M\left(1-v^{n-k+1} \right)
$$
with $v=\frac{1}{1+r}$ and the principal payment is
$$
P_k=M v^{n-k+1}
$$
so that $M=P_k+I_k$ and the oustanding balance is
$$
B_k=Ma_{\overline{n-k}|r}
$$
If the outstanding balance at month $k-1$ is known, i.e. what is left to be paid back, and the payment $M$, we can find the interest payed at month $k$ as 
$$
I_k=rB_{k-1}
$$
and $P_k=M-I_k$.

The monthly repayment of the loan is equivalent to the yearly repayment of the loan with effective annual interest $$j=\left(1+\frac{i}{12}\right)^{12}-1=(1+r)^{12}-1$$
for $m=n/12$ years:
$$
S=Ma_{\overline{n}|r}=M\frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^n}}{r}=M\frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+j)^m}}{r}=M\cdot\frac{j}{r}\cdot \frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+j)^m}}{j}=A a_{\overline{m}|j}
$$
observing that $(1+r)^n=(1+r)^{12\times\frac{n}{12}}=(1+j)^m$ and the yearly installment is $A=M\times\frac{j}{r}$. Observe that $A$ is the future vale at the end of the year of 12 installment of value $M$ at monthly interest $r$:
$$
A=M\times\frac{j}{r}=M\times\frac{(1+r)^{12}-1}{r}=M\cdot s_{\overline{12}|r}
$$
and expressing $r=i/12$ we have that
$$
A=M\times\frac{j}{r}=M\times\frac{j}{i/12}=12M\times\frac{j}{i}
$$
that is $A>12M$: the installment that we have to pay annually is greater than the sum of the monthly installments in one year, because the annual effective interest $j$ is greater than the monthly interest $i$:
$$
\frac{j}{i}=\frac{(1+i/12)^{12}-1}{i}>1\quad \text{for } i>0
$$

At any time $t$ (year) the interest payment is
$$
I_t=jAa_{\overline{m-t+1}|j}=A\left(1-\nu^{m-t+1} \right)
$$
with $\nu=\frac{1}{1+j}$ and the principal payment is
$$
P_t=A \nu^{m-t+1}
$$
so that $A =P_t+I_t$ and the oustanding balance is
$$
B_t=Aa_{\overline{m-t}|j}
$$
If the outstanding balance at year $t-1$ is known, i.e. what is left to be paid back, and the payment $A=Mj/r$ we can find the interest payed at year $t$ as 
$$
I_t=jB_{t-1}
$$
and $P_t=A-I_t$.

Comment: Thanks for the detail! Two questions remain. 1) Is $a_{\overline{m-t}|j} = 1$? Combining the equations for $I_t$ and $P_t$ it seems that way. Also, isn't $P_t + I_t$ the total annual payment rather than the outstanding balance, or am I misunderstanding terms? 2) What if, as in my example, $n$ and $m$ are not known but only previous payments (interest & principal) and what is left to be paid back are known?

Comment: 1) there was a mistake. ..sorry. 2) I'll   add it later

Comment: 1) Alright, makes sense now.  2) thanks!

Comment: 2) details added

Comment: Thanks, one more question though: Why is $12 \times M - P_t < I_t$`, that is why is what is actually paid in interest smaller than the calculated amount? I guess this comes down to the $j$ business: Shouldn't the effective interest rate be smaller than $i$ because the sum to be paid interest on decreases during the year? In fact, dividing $12 \times M - P_t $ by $B_{t-1}$ gives a lower rate than $i$.

Comment: $A$ is the equivalent payment of 12 monthly payments at the end of the year, that is the future value at the end of the year of 12 payments of value $M$. See added details

Comment: You have $12\times M \times \frac{j}{i}-P_t=I_t$.

Comment: Now I see! $I_t$ is the interest payment at the end of year $t$ that is equivalent to having payments at the end of each month of year $t$. Because the monthly payments are made earlier, their sum is smaller. However, I am looking for this sum. Any idea how this can be calculated?

Comment: I'm not sure to well understand...If you pay $M$ each month, at the end of the year $t\ge 1$ you have payed $12M$ as installment and interest $$I_t=\sum_{k=12(t-1)+1}^{12t}I_k$$ Is this the sum that you want to find?

Comment: Yes. The $12M$ part is clear, but I am looking to find the sum of interest payments you mentioned. Of course I can get it from $12M - (B_{t-1} - B_t)$, but I wonder whether I can get it directly.

Comment: No, your formula is wrong. You can find the interest payed at time $t$ as $$I_t=\sum_{k=12(t-1)+1}^{12t}I_k=\sum_{k=12(t-1)+1}^{12t}M\left(1-v^{n-k+1}\right)=12M-Mv^{n-12t}a_{\overline{12}|r}$$

Comment: Why would it be wrong? Intuitively, the annual interest payment is the sum of monthly payments minus the annual principal payment. But thanks adding the equation -- one last question: $a_{\overline{12}|r} = \big( \frac{1}{1+r} \big)^{12+1}$?

Comment: 1) It's wrong because the difference between the balance $B_k$ and $B_{k-12}$ (12 months before) is just $12M$. Each payment $M=I_k+P_k$ contains interest and principal! 2) $a_{\overline {12}|r}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^{12}}}{r}$ and in general the annuity is $ a_{\overline {n}|r}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{(1+r)^{n}}}{r}=\frac{1-v^n}{r} $ where $v=\frac{1}{1+r}$.

Comment: The first one works, thanks a lot! The easier way does not really but perhaps I misunderstand what an outstanding balance is. I thought it was the part of the loan left to be paid at $t$, that is the original loan minus all the principal payments until $t$.

Answer (score 0):

In situation, where $S_t > 12M$, we can use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator#Monthly_payment_formula) formula:

> The fixed monthly payment $M$ for a loan of $S$ for $n$ months and a monthly interest rate $i$ is:
>   $$M=S\frac{i(1+i)^n}{(1+i)^n-1}$$

After some transformations you obtain the number of months to pay this loan:
$$n=\log _{i+1} \frac{M}{M-Si}$$
So the total value of loan to pay in the last year $t$ is equal to
$$M\log _{i+1} \frac{M}{M-iS_{t-1}}$$